# configuring .htaccess file after migration in expressionengine

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

So basically I've moved a site from the original top domain to a folder in my site but the page is blank due to the .htaccess not automatically redirect to /en/

I tried placed my domain, julianjosephs.com before the existing domain but it didn't work. Not sure what to do now.

Original: `http://morganstachs.com/en/`

Development: `http://julianjosephs.com/morganstachs.com/`

***.htaccess file contents***

```
# -- LG .htaccess Generator Start --

# .htaccess generated by LG .htaccess Generator v1.0.0
# http://leevigraham.com/cms-customisation/expressionengine/addon/lg-htaccess-generator/

# secure .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

# Dont list files in index pages
IndexIgnore *

# EE 404 page for missing pages
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?/

# Simple 404 for missing files
<FilesMatch "(\.jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)$">
  ErrorDocument 404 "File Not Found"
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# remove the www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Add a trailing slash to paths without an extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# Remove index.php
# Uses the "include method"
# http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Remove_index.php_From_URLs/#Include_List_Method
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5})$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(_includes|site|landing_pages|listings_shortcut|offers|scripts|xml|en|sp|fr|members|P[0-9]{2,8}) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# Remove IE image toolbar
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
  Header set imagetoolbar "no"
</FilesMatch>

# -- LG .htaccess Generator End --

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.morganstachs\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.admin\.morganstachs\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/morganstachs\.com\:2082" [R=301,L]
```